# How to trigger a custom jQuery event from Flash, passing some data through event object?

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3

How to trigger a custom jQuery event from Flash, passing some data through event object?

Answer (score 0):

If you can trigger it with JavaScript, just invoke JS function with [ExternalInterface.call.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use if I'm passing a string to JS from AS3:

```
ExternalInterface.call("showBox",as3String);
```

And then you'd get that from JS using:

```
function showBox(myString){

}
```